# Reflect method names and types to function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to dynamically generate interfaces or infer types from class methods?

MWE below with `MyInterface` created manually from `MyClass`:

```
// Target class
class MyClass {
    public stringToNumber = (value: string): number => {
        return Number(value);
    };
    public numberToString = (value: number): string => {
        return value.toString();
    };
}

// Interface i wish to generate
interface MyInterface {
    stringToNumber: [string, number]; // methodName: [methodInput, methodOutput]
    numberToString: [number, string]; // ...
}

// Function that wraps my class
const myClassFn = <
    K extends keyof MyInterface,
    V extends MyInterface[K][0],
    Z extends MyInterface[K][1]
>(
    method: K,
    value: V
): Z => {
    return (new MyClass()[method] as any)(value);
};

// Usage
const result = myClassFn("numberToString", 1);
```

I.e. can something like `MyInterface` be directly generated from `MyClass` or (even better) be inferred via generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the type that you want using mapped types and `infer`/`extends`:

```
type MyClassMethods<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (input: infer I) => infer O ? [I, O] : never;
}
```

Using this on your class

```
type MyInterface = MyClassMethods<MyClass>
```

resolves to

```
type MyInterface = {
    stringToNumber: [string, number];
    numberToString: [number, string];
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vo0m)

---

We can improve on this in order to support methods with more than one argument.  We don't actually need the `MyInterface`.  We just need to know the method names.  We make the function a generic which depends on the method name and we use the built-in utility types `Parameters` and `ReturnType` to get the other values.

```
class MyClass {
    public someProp: number = 5;
    public stringToNumber = (value: string): number => {
        return Number(value);
    };
    public numberToString = (value: number): string => {
        return value.toString();
    };
    public add = (a: number, b: number): number => {
        return a + b;
    };
}

type MethodNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof T]

const myClassFn = <
    K extends MethodNames<MyClass>
>(
    method: K,
    ...value: Parameters<MyClass[K]>
): ReturnType<MyClass[K]> => {
    return (new MyClass()[method] as any)(...value);
};

console.log( myClassFn("numberToString", 1) );
console.log( myClassFn("add", 1, 2));
console.log( myClassFn("stringToNumber", "5"));
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0vON)

---

We could even apply this to any class that can be constructed with no arguments. (Though really it makes more sense that we would pass an instance rather than a constructor).

```
const makeClassFn = <C extends {}>(constructor: new () => C) =>
    <K extends MethodNames<C>>(
        method: K,
        ...value: Parameters<C[K]>
    ): ReturnType<C[K]> => {
        return (new constructor()[method] as any)(...value);
    };

const myClassFn = makeClassFn(MyClass);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wRpREm)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and taking it further by demonstrating a more general solution – which is what I was eventually going for!